# S3 mini switches off randomly

Tags: charging, mute

1. My S3 mini switches off when I use social media or browse internet, then won't switch on until I have put it on charge but then it has 75% battery, just comes off charge and then the same thing happens.
2. When I make or receive calls, it would mute on its own, turn on the bluetooth and/or just switch off.

Please advise what the problem could be.

Thanks

RG

Comment: Is you phone rooted? Does this happen when you connect to a wifi network too? Just put your phone in airplane mode and see what happens

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing a factory reset, if that doesn't work it might be a faulty battery

Comment: -1, Nothing personal. I would definitely take it back if you first backup your claim about faulty battery. Also note  that asking clarifications is done via comments (subject to 50+ rep points). Please avoid it in the answer. Thanks!